# Linux C processes pids global visibility

Tags: c, linux, process, global, pid

Hello yesterday I have one question it is here:
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127819/linux-c-comunication-beetween-processes-using-signals-and-pipes)

And now I have other problem, I have the code based on answer by [some guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1979174/some-guy)

And now I have a problem I need for all children to see the pids of other child, how can i do that?? I try using global variables, but maybe in wrong way.

Please help I need a fast answer

Comment: Try using one of the "Inter Process Communication" techniques like message passing or shared memory. Global variables is not shared among processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file with the parent process and write pids of all children. Read this file from the children after some delay. You can write out, `N`, the number of children first and then `N` lines each line containing one pid.